# Jquery keyup events fail in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, events, model-view-controller, key

I have a MVC page that is called by redirecttoaction. Jquery key events fail even when event delegation is on. They are not picked up.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>keydown demo</title>
  <style>
  fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
  }
  #print-output {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .print-output-line {
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: monaco, monospace;
    font-size: .7em;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/events.js"></script>

<script>
var xTriggered = 0;
$( "#target" ).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
  xTriggered++;
  var msg = "Handler for .keydown() called " + xTriggered + " time(s).";
  $.print( msg, "html" );
  $.print( event );
});

$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).keydown();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

looks like DOM object is not listening to key events. ALthough I can attach a key event to a particular control.

Comment: what you have tried... provide codes..

Comment: $('#textbox').keyup(function(event){
 $('#msg-keyup').html('keyup() is triggered!, keyCode = ' 
              + event.keyCode + ' which = ' + event.which)
});  tried all key events

Comment: `Edit` your question and provide `demo code` there ... it will be much readable